# Renaming burned CDs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, plug-and-play

I'm stuck with a problem that would require a skill set a little farther than mine, I currently
installed Ubuntu for the first time on a piece of hardware, but I didn't take in account that the computer that I had installed it on only had a ethernet port, and I had to use a external USB Plug and play device to get it working, after searching for a while, I noticed that I can use ndiswrapper so I can use the windows drivers. Then I came into another problem, when trying to install the drivers from the application store, it told me to stick in the original boot CD that I installed ubuntu with, but from what it seems, the CD has to be specifically named in order for the application store to use it.

I was wondering if there is way of changing a name of a already burned CD?

Comment: You can't..  A CD can only be written once unless its a CD-RW disk

Comment: You will have to RIP it to an ISO, or similiar and edit the name.  Then make a brand new CD and use that.  As Ramhound said CD are read only.